# How to ignore blank lines when taking data from txt files

Tags: php, laravel-8

Blank lines cause a problem when I taking data from the txt file

**The txt file:**

```
23/04/2021,Ulusal egemenlik ve çocuk bayramı

12/05/2021,Ramazan bayramı 1.gün
13/05/2021,Ramazan bayramı 2.gün
14/05/2021,Ramazan bayramı 3.gün
15/05/2021,Ramazan bayramı 4.gün
```

**The function is:**

```
public static function uploadDataFromFile(){

    $filePath = public_path().'/files/tatiller.txt';
    $read = fopen($filePath,"r",);

    while (!feof($read)){

        $contents = fgets($read);

            $contentArray = explode(",", $contents);

            list($date, $desc) = $contentArray; // ---> Here i taking the ErrorException Undefined offset: 1

            DB::table('holidays')->insert(
                [
                    'date' => $date, 
                    'description' => $desc, 
                    'type' => 0
                ]
            );
        
    }

    fclose($read);
}
```

What I can do to ignore these lines?

Comment: Check if that line has a length of zero size, if so, skip it (e.g. continue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the line has a 0 length:

```
if (strlen($contents) == 0) continue;
```

but that would still fail if you had a line with whitespace in it or perhaps just a date. It might be safer to check for a comma instead as that should be a better indication of valid data on the line:

```
if (strpos($contents, ',') === false) continue;
```